# How to interpret 2 variables separated by a comma in chained inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, notation

What does $0\le x,y\le1$ mean? See the red circled part in the image below for an example.

1. I first thought it meant: $x\ge0$ and $y\le1$
2. Then I thought it meant: $0\le x\le y \le 1 $
3. But, based on the green part, I believe it means: $x$ and $y$ are in $[0,1]$

Is this notation unambiguous? In probability, the comma means $\bigcap$, so, to me, these are "separate" statements, as in (1) and not (3).

[image]

Comment: I would also interpret is as (c).

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. If you were to write out "a", how would you properly do it? Maybe $0 \le x \le \infty$, $-\infty \le y \le 1$

Comment: $0\leq x \text{ and } y \leq 1$

Comment: @HJ_beginner  What you have written after your edit is also correct.

Comment: Saying that the comma means `and` may not help. You could still interpret it as either `(0 <= x) and (y <= 1)` or `0 <= (x and y) <= 1` :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would take it as c, that both $x$ and $y$ are between $0$ and $1$ and think that it should be unambiguous.  I might have a worry in my stomach that it was $a$ and be alert to the possibility as I read on or check back to make sure.  I would say b is wrong and should be written the way you did.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is a somewhat dangerous notation. If the spacing were different: $$0\le x,\quad y\le 1$$ you could think it was _a_. However, a would more often be written as $$x\ge 0,\quad y\le 1$$

Comment: I would only ever have read that as $x\geq 0 $ *and* $y\leq 1$.

Answer (score 15):

It is a convention for $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$ and is mostly to avoid typing it out twice. The comma is used this way in the equivalent statement $x,y \in [0,1]$ as well so it's consistent with that notation.

Answer (score 4):

The overall integral of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ has to be one. Let's then compare the different assumptions.

**(a)**

The integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^1x+\frac32y^2\ dy\ dx$$

is not convergent.

**(b)**

$$\int_0^{1}\int_{x}^1x+\frac32y^2\ dy\ dx=\int_0^1x+\frac12-x^2-\frac12x^3\ dx=\frac{13}{24}\not=1.$$

**(c)**

$$\color{green}{\int_0^{1}\int_{0}^1x+\frac32y^2\ dy\ dx=\int_0^1x+\frac12\ dx=1}.$$

So, interpretation (c) seems to be correct.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing that out. You're right I was getting very strange answers because I misinterpreted the region of $x$ and $y$. I was getting frustrated until I realized I was reading the problem wrong. Thanks.